# .Net Core 2 & AngularJS SPA Not Working

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I've been migrating a project over to .NET Core 2 from .NET Framework and the process was smoother than expected, however when I thought I had overcome to most difficult challenges, I can't for the life of me get the SPA aspect to work.

When I launch the app, it works fine so long as I go to the root (https://localhost:5001) and I can navigate with the Angular routing just fine. However if I try and load a page via a route, eg. https://localhost:5001/login, I get a generic Chrome 404 "This localhost page can’t be found".

My `index.html` is in the directory `MyApp/Pages/` and my client-side code is in `MyApp/wwwroot/app/`. When moving the `index.html` into the `wwwroot` folder I get nothing at all.

In My `Startup.cs`, here is how I've set it up:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        } 

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        var defaultFileOptions = new DefaultFilesOptions();
        defaultFileOptions.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
        defaultFileOptions.DefaultFileNames.Add("/index.html");
        app.UseDefaultFiles(defaultFileOptions);
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
                !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                await next();
            }
        });

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

I've tried numerous guides but it seems that most that I can find are extremely outdated, or when trying to use methods in the posts, they're methods that I don't have. Any help is highly appreciated as I'd quite like to finish the migration and continue working on the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my problem was in the way that I was handling the 404. I was doing `context.Request.Path = "/index.html";` in my Startup.cs, but it still couldn't resolve the html file, so instead I made it redirect back to the root path:

```cs
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next();
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
            !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
        {
            // This is what I changed. I need to resolve to "/" instead of "/index.html"
            context.Request.Path = "/";
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            await next();
        }
    });
```

Thanks to @Anton Danylov for his suggestion pointing me to revisit that section of code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you have an SPA, and Angular has it's own routing, but when you try to use an URL like this https://localhost:5001/login, this route is served by MVC and not by Angular, MVC does not find appropriate controller and returns 404 as a result.

What you should do, is to return index.html in response to such requests, so that Angular routing could take care of it. You may take a look at this article:

https://www.toptal.com/angular/angular-5-asp-net-core

Comment: Thanks for the response, the link didn't help me a great deal as it's "new Angular"  and the Web.config trick didn't work for me. "What you should do, is to return index.html in response to such requests" is what got me thinking about my startup.cs code again - My handling of the 404 response was wrong! About to post the fix.

Answer (score 0):

use from this code :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseBrowserLink();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
}
```

Follow link: [Application startup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: This doesn't help in my case as I don't actually want any MVC routes. I found my issue, about to post it.